# Is there a way to create Columnfamily in external table dynamically?

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql

I created a External Table like this:

```
 CREATE External TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  words  (word string, timest string, 
    url string, occs string, nos string, hiveall string, occall string) STORED 
    BY org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
    ('hbase.columns.mapping' =':key, count:timest,  count:url, count:occs, 
    count:nos, other:hiveall, other:occall ')
```

Is there any way to create the columnfamilys dynamically? so that i have for example something like this:

```
1397897857000      column=word:occall, timestamp=1449778100184, value=value1

1397897857000      column=otherword:occall, timestamp=1449778100184, value=value2
```

I thought about something like this but from hive, this code here is from hbase :

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
String table = "myTable";

admin.disableTable(table);

HColumnDescriptor cf1 = ...;
admin.addColumn(table, cf1);      // adding new ColumnFamily
HColumnDescriptor cf2 = ...;
admin.modifyColumn(table, cf2);    // modifying existing ColumnFamily

admin.enableTable(table);
```

from here:
http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/schema.html

Or does somebody has another idea for my Problem:
 I have multiple data from a word count job. This data contains the url, where the word was read from, a timestamp ,when the word was read, the occurance of how often it was found in the url, and some information about a category( there are news, social and all) with the occurance. The main problem is that multiple words can occur at the same timestamp, which will override a existing one. I need the rowkey to be the timestamp to make some querys against it ( like what was most used word in the last 2 weeks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column families can't be changed after creation like this. In your scenario, you should create different column qualifiers instead of different column families.

Fix a column family and use word coming as qualifier name. So, it will not override when different words come at the same timestamp.

Comment: How can i set dynamically the words into the qualifier and how can I differ the diffrent values then?  What I understand is something like this here then:  1397897857000      column=count:word, timestamp=1449778100184, value=valueFromWhatExactly?

1397897857000      column=count:otherword, timestamp=1449778100184, value=valueFromWhatExactly?                                                                   I dont want to save all entries in one line, because it should be fast to ask a timestamp which words ( and also which attributes) it has.

Comment: Alternative could be to append the word in the row key itself after timestamp and store all other attributes in column qualifiers corresponding to that.

Comment: Can i store a map as a rowkkey? if yes how can i do that because the words are dynamically.

Comment: Didn't understand your problem. What is meant by map? I meant append each word after timestamp as a Row Key.

Comment: I mean something like this [timestamp,word]

Comment: Ok. So, better try the approach of my last comment. Use 'timestamp+word' as Row Key. Hope it helps.. 
P.S.: If you got the desired response, please accept the answer. :)